# Does it make sense to talk about origin of self?

Tags: anatman, pratityasamutpada, atman

In dependent origination at what stage self comes into picture ? Does self originate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dependent origination, the stage self comes into picture is at '*attachment*' and is full mature at '*birth*'. As a modern Indian, you (the questioner) should know the word '*jati*' ('*birth*') does not mean '*physical birth from the mother*' but means '*self or social identity*'.

> Jāti (in Devanagari: जाति, Bengali: জাতি, Telugu:జాతి, Kannada:ಜಾತಿ,
>   Malayalam: ജാതി, Tamil:ஜாதி, literally "birth") is a group of clans,
>   tribes, communities and sub-communities, and religions in India. Each
>   jāti typically has an association with a traditional job function or
>   tribe. Religious beliefs (e.g. Sri Vaishnavism or Veera Shaivism) or
>   linguistic groupings may define some jatis. A person's surname
>   typically reflects a community (jati) association: thus Gandhi =
>   perfume seller, Dhobi = washerman, Srivastava = military scribe, Ror =
>   Warriors etc. Wikipedia

The self certainly originates, as described in many suttas below:

> And what is clinging? These four are clingings: sensuality clinging,
>   view clinging, precept & practice clinging, and doctrine of **self**
>   clinging. This is called clinging.
>
> SN 12.2
>
> ---
>
> The craving that makes for further becoming — accompanied by passion &
>   delight, relishing now here & now there — i.e., craving for sensual
>   pleasure, craving for becoming, craving for non-becoming: This, friend
>   Visakha, is the **origination of** **self-identification** described by the
>   Blessed One.
>
> MN 44
>
> ---
>
> There is the case where an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person — who
>   has no regard for noble ones, is not well-versed or disciplined in
>   their Dhamma; who has no regard for men of integrity, is not
>   well-versed or disciplined in their Dhamma — assumes form to be the
>   **self**. That assumption is a fabrication. Now what is the cause, what is
>   the origination, what is the birth, what is the coming-into-existence
>   of that fabrication? To an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person,
>   touched by that which is felt born of contact with ignorance, craving
>   arises. That fabrication [of **self**] is born of that. And that fabrication is
>   inconstant, fabricated, dependently co-arisen. That craving... That
>   feeling... That contact... That ignorance is inconstant, fabricated,
>   dependently co-arisen.
>
> SN 22.81
>
> ---
>
> This, monks, is the path of practice leading to **self**-identification.
>   One assumes about the eye that 'This is me, this is my self, this is
>   what I am.' One assumes about forms... One assumes about consciousness
>   at the eye... One assumes about contact at the eye... One assumes
>   about feeling... One assumes about craving that 'This is me, this is
>   my self, this is what I am.'
>
> "One assumes about the ear...
>
> "One assumes about the nose...
>
> "One assumes about the tongue...
>
> "One assumes about the body...
>
> "One assumes about the intellect that 'This is me, this is my self,
>   this is what I am.' One assumes about ideas... One assumes about
>   consciousness at the intellect... One assumes about contact at the
>   intellect... One assumes about feeling... One assumes about craving
>   that 'This is me, this is my self, this is what I am.'
>
> MN 148
>
> ---
>
> Who, O Lord, has a sense-impression?"
>
> "The question is not correct," said the Exalted One.
>
> "I do not say that 'he has a sense-impression.' Had I said so, then
>   the question 'Who has a sense-impression?' would be appropriate. But
>   since I did not speak thus, the correct way to ask the question will
>   be 'What is the condition of sense-impression?' And to that the
>   correct reply is: 'The sixfold sense-base is a condition of
>   sense-impression, and sense-impression is the condition of feeling.'"
>
> "Who, O Lord, feels?"
>
> "The question is not correct," said the Exalted One. "I do not say
>   that 'he feels.' Had I said so, then the question 'Who feels?' would
>   be appropriate. But since I did not speak thus, the correct way to ask
>   the question will be 'What is the condition of feeling?' And to that
>   the correct reply is: 'sense-impression is the condition of feeling;
>   and feeling is the condition of craving.'"
>
> "Who, O Lord, craves?"
>
> "The question is not correct," said the Exalted One. "I do not say
>   that 'he craves.' Had I said so, then the question 'Who craves?' would
>   be appropriate. But since I did not speak thus, the correct way to ask
>   the question will be 'What is the condition of craving?' And to that
>   the correct reply is: 'Feeling is the condition of craving, and
>   craving is the condition of clinging.'"
>
> "Who, O Lord, clings?"
>
> "The question is not correct," said the Exalted One, "I do not say
>   that 'he clings.' Had I said so, then the question 'Who clings?' would
>   be appropriate. But since I did not speak thus, the correct way to ask
>   the question will be 'What is the condition of clinging?' And to that
>   the correct reply is: 'Craving is the condition of clinging; and
>   **clinging** is the condition of the process of **becoming**.' Such is the
>   origin of this entire mass of suffering.
>
> SN 12.2

Comment: Ignorance can arise when one is not aware of the teachings of Buddha Dhamma. Dhamma states Anatta. Therefore I think self is found where ignorance is found.

Answer (score 0):

The five aggregates described by the buddha forma the illusion of self...the self is impermenant and it perpetuates...like a candle fron another candle...like that flame the self continues...
So as per the question goes...there is no point in talking about the origin of self...as it does not originate anywhere...it will be like trying to search fot origin of water seen due to mirage...

Comment: How did the illusion of self originate ? That's what I am asking.

Comment: Only answer tobthis question I have ever read is Osho's explaination of seven doors how ego enters the mind...as this firum is not about Osho I am not putting it here...you can search it on google...those seven doors is how ego enters the mind and the ego is nothing but illusion of a seperate self...and that is how it originates...